# How to count for each row using other table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: book table and author table. I need to count for each author how many book is registered in book table. How to do that?

Comment: provide us with the schemes of your tables

Comment: `select author, count(*) from book group by author`

Comment: Are you sure you have only 2 tables? What happens if a book has multiple authors? Btw get familiar with group by and count.

Comment: You should at least try by yourself and show us where do you have problems.  A piece of code with schema of the tables would be great as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT Count(dbo.Book.ID)
        FROM   dbo.Book
        WHERE  dbo.Book.AuthorID = dbo.Author.ID) AS NumberOfBooks
FROM   dbo.Author
```

You must connect two tables with an ID, so you can find out the relation of two tables.

Comment: This is overcomplicated and inefficient. Moreover, this follows ms sql syntax, not mysql.

Comment: So what do you suggest? Can you put more efficient way?

Comment: If you use Views for that type reporting, It will be better.

Comment: @m0riartis I already told you in a comment: use group by and count.

Comment: **EDIT**
SELECT Count(dbo.Book.ID),dbo.Author.Name  FROM dbo.Book INNER JOIN dbo.Author ON dbo.Book.AuthorID=dbo.Author.ID GROUP BY dbo.Author.Name

Answer (score 0):

There is a group function in sql statements that is named count you can add group in 
for example

```
SELECT author_name
       Count(books.id)
FROM   author,
       book
WHERE  book.author_id = author_id 
GROUP BY AUTHOR
```

it will help u i guess

Comment: This is going return result for a single author, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have practiced your question is **SQLFIDDLE**.

Here is the **SQL Schema** I've used:

```
create table book(  
  book_id int,
  author_name varchar(100),
  book_name varchar(100)
);
create table author(  
 author_id int,
 author_name varchar(100)
);
insert into author values(1, 'shovon');
insert into author values(11, 'arsho');
insert into author values(111, 'soda');
insert into author values(1111, 'nfs');
insert into book values(1, 'shovon', 'book shovon 1');
insert into book values(2, 'soda', 'book soda 1');
insert into book values(3, 'shovon', 'book shovon 2');
insert into book values(4, 'arsho', 'book arsho 1');
insert into book values(5, 'ar', 'book ar 1');
```

Here is the query I've used:

```
select a.author_name, count(b.book_name) from 
(author as a 
  left join book as b on 
  a.author_name=b.author_name) 
group by a.author_name
order by count(b.book_name) desc;
```

Url of **SQLFIDDLE** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f11bc5/22